# How we can merge all csv file in same directory by column name?

Tags: python, csv

I have hundreds of CSV. Each have some common column but after each have different number of column with date as column name.

For example.

```
File210
Symbol,other_column,other_column2,20MAR17

File209
Symbol,other_column,other_column2,19MAR17,20MAR17

File208
Symbol,other_column,other_column2,18MAR17,19MAR17,20MAR17
```

Here each file have different data for each symbol for specific date.

Output file should have null value for symbol

How can I merge all file so all symbol from each file is include and data will be comes under  same column name?

Some symbol in file210 have no value for date  18 and 19 March so it should be null. No zero or no -(hiphen), same as sysmbol in file209 have no value for 18 then it should also be null.

On daily basis all file update and one column added with that day value.

Comment: Do the CSV files have column names? If so, then merging them with the help of [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) should be rather easy - you read them one by one, combine into one dict and them save it.

Comment: yes its column name. may you comment code sample which is useful for above example file.

Comment: Are you also joining on the symbol?

Comment: Please show some lines of input and associated expected output.

Comment: SYMBOL,PRICE_WHEN_ADD,DELIV_PER,PL_PER,DATE,Remarks,2017-03-20
ALANKIT,22.4,5.58,-0.884955752212,2017-03-20,bulk,22.4

SYMBOL,PRICE_WHEN_ADD,DELIV_PER,PL_PER,DATE,Remarks,2017-03-16,2017-03-17,2017-03-20
ABFRL,152.75,74.18,2.68907563025,2017-03-16,1day,152.75,155.9,155.5

here column name is day to day date and it's add daily base in all file. when I merge all above csv, there should be output with all three dates columns name (or if more exist then more), 
for example, symbol "ALANKIT" in file1 has added on 20 so output file sholud have null value for other column like 16 and 17 march